Extract multiple occurrences of text between given strings in Google sheet
My input text, in a single cell, is the result of user choice selection. It is similar to (so its a string with multiple substrings):
"meal (20$)", "metro (5,5$)"

I would like to extract (to then sum) the prices of each individual choice, to have this sum result in another cell:
20+5,5

I have been searching around with the FIND and SPLIT function but I only succeeded to extract the first price with it. Another solution I see would be to split the text and use an ArrayFormula for the summation, but for now I do not find how to split with multiple characters.
I am using Google sheet, so I cannot use the TEXTSPLIT Excel function, and no macros.
So in a nutshell:



input cell
Desired output




"meal (20$)", "metro (5,5$)"
25,5



Note the comma, because my local is France.
Thank you for your help!

It's unclear whether you want to get the text string 20+5,5 or the sum 25,5. Please [edit] your question and add a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also specify the spreadsheet locale (File > Settings > Locale).

Use regexreplace(), split() and join(). Assuming that cell A2 contains the text string "meal (20$)", "metro (5,5$)", this formula will get the text string 20+5,5:
=join("+"; split(regexreplace(A2; "[^\d],|[^,\d]", " "); " "))

The get the sum of those numbers instead, use sum(), like this:
=sum(split(regexreplace(A2; "[^\d],|[^,\d]"; " "); " "))

The summation will only give the correct result when the decimal mark used in the text string matches the locale of the spreadsheet. In the event the spreadsheet is in a locale that uses a period as decimal mark, substitute() commas with periods, like this:
=sum(split(substitute(regexreplace(A2; "[^\d],|[^,\d]"; " "); ","; "."); " "))

See
regular expressions,
RE2,
regexreplace(),
split() and
join().

Thanks a lot, your sum formula works perfectly! Thank you also for including the decimal mark locals. I found the regexreplace method before but I did not make it work by inputting it parenthesis in regexreplace(A2; "(" ; " ") . I assume this is your \d here, how did you find that? Could you explain it more in your answer?

Added basic regex info links in the answer.

Here's a variation that assumes your text string is in cell A1. It is locale independent as long as the number strings match your locale:
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A1; "[()$""""]";); REGEXREPLACE(A1; "[$""""]";)))

# North American Syntax 
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[()$""""]",), REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[$""""]",)))
REGEXEXTRACT  REGEXREPLACE  SUMPRODUCT
Alternative
=INDEX(SUM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A1; "[()$""""]";);REGEXREPLACE(A1; "[$""""]";))*1))

# North American Syntax 
=INDEX(SUM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[()$""""]",),REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[$""""]",))*1))
INDEX  REGEXEXTRACT  REGEXREPLACE  SUM
Explantion
1  |  =SUMPRODUCT(
2  |     REGEXEXTRACT(
3  |       REGEXREPLACE(A1; "[()$""""]";);
4  |        REGEXREPLACE(A1; "[$""""]";)))

A1 = "meal (20$)", "metro (5,5$)"   // one string including quotes & commas


SUMPRODUCT is used to get the SUM because it is an array function and causes the REGEXREPLACE and REGEXEXTRACT functions nested within to also behave as array functions.
The REGEXREPLACE on line #3 removes the characters $, ", (, and ) from the string:
= REGEXREPLACE(A1; "[()$""""]";)
= "meal 20, metro 5,5"   // one string with no quotes


The REGEXREPLACE on line #4 removes the characters $ and " from the string:
= REGEXREPLACE(A1; "[$""""]";)
= "meal (20), metro (5,5)"  // one string with no quotes


The REGEXEXTRACT on line #2 uses the REGEXREPLACE from line #3 as its text argument, and the one from line #4 as its regular expression:
= REGEXEXTRACT("meal 20, metro 5,5"; "meal (20), metro (5,5)")
= {"20"; "5,5"}       // an array of two strings


SUMPRODUCT returns the SUM of the array because they are text strings after coercing the number strings to numbers:
= SUMPRODUCT({"20"; "5,5"})
= 25,5

!!! If they were not strings the result would be different:
= SUMPRODUCT({20; 5,5})
= 110



Alternative
Slightly longer and uses INDEX(SUM(txt_array*1))) instead of SUMPRODUCT(txt_array)
=INDEX(
   SUM(
     REGEXEXTRACT(
       REGEXREPLACE(A1; "[()$""""]";);
       REGEXREPLACE(A1; "[$""""]";))*1))

Explanation

The INDEX function is an array function and serves only to make the nested functions behave as array function which they are not natively.  In this application it serves the same purpose as ARRAYFORMULA but is shorter to write (a common theme with me ;-)
Bullets #2-#4 are the same as in the previous formula and we're left with the same array of number  strings which are then multiplied by 1 to coerce them to numbers. This is applied to each item in the array because the formula is nested in INDEX:
= INDEX({"20"; "5,5"}*1)
= {"20"*1; "5,5"*1}
= {20; 5,5}  

but, the non-array version returns:
= {"20"; "5,5"}*1
= "20"*1
= 20


Finally the SUM function is used to return the result:
= SUM({20; 5,5})  
= 25,5




I did not know regexextract, thank you for this well explained answer! Could you explain what the INDEX(SUM()) does? When would we prefer this alternative?

There are often different approaches to the same task. The accepted answer is a good one. The reason for INDEX is that I needed an array function, and I needed to SUM the array, and SUMPRODUCT provided a shorter solution given you are working with number strings. If your requirements changed my choices might as well.
